# how do I figure out what is causing the space issue with CSS and bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm struggling to get parts of the CSS to work right on my form that uses Bootstrap v5.3.

Most of my page rows have this little purple, rectangular spacer in front.

[image: screenshot.with.rectangle]

I don't know why the rectangle is there, but it is consistent on the display.

Once I get into my Razor code, I loop to display the phone numbers. When I do that, the little purple spacer vanishes and my row is not lined up with the others:

[image: screenshot.without.rectangle]

In the Inspector code, you can see that both DIV tags have the same information, but the 2nd one is missing that little rectangular area.

I want to correct that, but I don't understand why it does it in the first place, so I don't know how to recreate it when it does not happen.

In site.css:

```css
.row {
  --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
  --bs-gutter-y: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: calc(-1 * var(--bs-gutter-y));
  margin-right: calc(-0.5 * var(--bs-gutter-x));
  margin-left: calc(-0.5 * var(--bs-gutter-x));
}
.row > * {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * 0.5);
  padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * 0.5);
  margin-top: var(--bs-gutter-y);
}
  .col-md-2 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-md-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
```

In Account.razor:

```html
@page "/Account/{appid:long}"
@inherits BaseAppState

<PageTitle>@_title</PageTitle>
    <h3>@_title</h3>
<style>
    .validation-message {
        list-style-type: none;
        color: red;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .validation-errors ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        color: #B94A48;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
</style>


    <EditForm OnValidSubmit="@Submit" FormName="Account" class="h-100" Model="@_data">
        <Blazored.FluentValidation.FluentValidationValidator/>
        <div class="container main-container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <ValidationSummary />
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1">
                    <label class="pi-item-label" for="FirstName">First Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <InputText id="FirstName" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" @bind-Value="@_data.FirstName" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label class="pi-item-label" for="MiddleName">Middle Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <InputText id="MiddleName" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" @bind-Value="@_data.MiddleName" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="pi-item-label" for="LastName">Last Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <InputText id="LastName" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" @bind-Value="@_data.LastName" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label class="pi-item-label" for="Suffix">Suffix</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <InputText id="Suffix" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" @bind-Value="@_data.Suffix" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                    <label class="pi-item-label" for="HomeAddress">Home Address</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <InputText id="HomeAddress" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@_data.LineOne" />
                        <ValidationMessage For="() => _data.LineOne" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                    <label class="pi-item-label" for="HomeAddressLine2">Home Address Line 2</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <InputText id="HomeAddressLine2" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@_data.LineTwo" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1">
                    <label class="pi-item-label" for="CityName">City / Town</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <InputText id="CityName" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@_data.CityName" />
                        <ValidationMessage For="() => _data.CityName" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label class="pi-item-label" for="StateId">State</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <InputSelect class="form-select" id="StateId"
                            @bind-Value="@_data.StateId"
                            disabled="@(!_data.HasStates)">
                            <option value="" />
                            @foreach (var item in _states)
                            {
                                <option value="@item.StateId" selected="@(_data.StateId == item.StateId)">@item.Name</option>
                            }
                        </InputSelect>
                        <ValidationMessage For="() => _data.StateId" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label class="pi-item-label" for="PostalCode">Postal Code</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <InputText id="PostalCode" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@_data.PostalCode" />
                        <ValidationMessage For="() => _data.PostalCode" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="pi-item-label" for="CountryId">Country</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <InputSelect class="form-select" id="CountryId"
                            Value="@_data.CountryId"
                            ValueChanged="@((int? countryId) => GetStateList(countryId))"
                            ValueExpression="@(() => _data.CountryId)">
                            <option value="" />
                            @foreach (var item in _countries)
                            {
                                <option value="@item.CountryId">@item.Name</option>
                            }
                        </InputSelect>
                        <ValidationMessage For="() => _data.CountryId" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1">
                    <label class="pi-item-label" for="Email">Email</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <InputText id="Email" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" @bind-Value="@_data.Email" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label class="pi-item-label" for="CountryOfCitizenship">Country of Citizenship</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <InputSelect class="form-select" id="CountryOfCitizenship" @bind-Value="@_data.CountryOfCitizenshipID">
                            <option value="" />
                            @foreach (var item in _countries)
                            {
                                <option value="@item.CountryId">@item.Name</option>
                            }
                        </InputSelect>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                    <label class="pi-item-label">Phone Numbers</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            @foreach (var obj in _data.PhoneNumbers.Select((phone, idx) => new { idx, phone }))
            {
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-1">
                        <InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value="@obj.phone.PhoneTypeId" aria-label="@($"Type for Phone Number #{obj.idx + 1}")">
                            <option value="0" />
                            @foreach (var option in _phoneTypes)
                            {
                                <option value="@option.Id">@option.Value</option>
                            }
                        </InputSelect>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-secondary">
                                <SVGIcon Icon="SVGIcon.SVGIconLookup.Phone" aria-hidden="true" />
                            </button>
                            <InputText type="text" aria-label="Phone Dial Number" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@obj.phone.DialNumber" />
                            @if (1 < _data.PhoneNumbers.Count)
                            {
                                <button type="button" @onclick="@(() => DeletePhoneNumber(obj.phone.PhoneNumberId))" class="btn btn-danger">
                                    <SVGIcon Icon="SVGIcon.SVGIconLookup.Times" Title="@($"Delete {@obj.phone.DialNumber}")" />
                                </button>
                            }
                            <ValidationMessage For="() => obj" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                </div>
            }
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-auto offset-md-1">
                    @if (_data.PhoneNumbers.Count < 3)
                    {
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="@(() => AddPhoneNumber())">Add Phone Number</button>
                    }
                </div>
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-auto">
                    <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="btn btn-am-primary @_buttonSuccessCss" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
```

Would anyone be able to help with this?

Comment: The "spacer" is just empty space that is left when there is enough space in the parent container set to `display: flex;`. When you add different content is uses more space for content, so they don't align. Please post a snippet with 2 rows, one old, and one new that doesn't align, and the CSS for that parent, and also children if they have flex: property defined. That might help determine how to strategize a layout that always aligns.

Comment: @prkos - I added most of the code. The actual CSS file is 12280 lines, so I just pasted up what I think I am using.

Comment: Your code isn't in a format that can easily be debugged. Please don't copy from templates, copy generated HTML from a rendered page using Web tools. Delete everything that doesn't contribute to your problem. Delete parts of code, bit by bit, check if it affects you, until you arrive to the minimal code where the problem is still present. Copy it out into a blank HTML, and then construct a snippet: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: Just by looking at the screenshot it seems the difference is the column class, the desired ones have .col-md-5 while yours have  .col-md-2, they have different width assigned. Can you place your content into a different column configuration so it ends up with the .col-md-5 class and see if it helps?

Comment: @prkos unfortunately, I cannot. I initially created the view as you described above, but the work order requires the new page to be identical to the old page. The old page has the 2 phone number fields directly below the City and State. I can get my phone numbers to fit into that area, but then they move left to become out of alignment.